# Browsers try to download html file instead of opening

Tags: html, wordpress

Browsers (Chrome and Safari) Try to download **[this](http://jonesvillerobotics/contactus.html)** html file when opened. It is only on that link that it tries to download it. Also note that internet explorer opens it without a problem.

The one thing that I think is causing this may be wordpress or some plugin within wordpress but it seems unlikely since no wordpress is used in that page.

[Contact html code](http://pastebin.com/Jkt7sadQ)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely an incorrect mime type in your .htaccess file. I suggest going into it and looking for any unwanted lines similar to the below and removing them.

```
AddHandler application/ etc.
```

and also ensure your type is set as follows:

```
AddType text/html .html
```

In order to open .htaccess in cPanel:
Click File Manager and make sure to tick Show Hidden Files (dotfiles) before clicking Go. Then the .htaccess should show up the location where wp (wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes) is installed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that there is a problem with your server configuration that is giving the visiting browser the wrong mime type.

The correct mime type for html is: text/html
The mime type that your server is sending is: application/x-httpd-php

You appear to be running Apache. As a result there are two possible files that could be causing this, either in .htaccess or in one of Apaches configuration files.

Try adding the text below to a .htaccess file in your directory, or look for a mention of application/x-httpd-php

```
AddType text/html .html
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following at it worked:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue a couple of times. The problem for me was the web server was automatically handling PHP requests outside of the .htaccess file. For some reason, changing settings in WordPress would sometimes cause a change in the .htaccess file, adding a handler for PHP. This would cause the server to burp at every PHP request thereafter and attempt to serve the file instead of handle it.

The solution, then, was to manually remove the handler that was automatically added to the .htaccess file (and leave a comment for myself so I wouldn't pull my hair out every time!)

Answer (score 0):

Had same thing happen to me. I know this sounds funny but check to make sure none of the keys on your keyboard are stuck. i.e) ALT key , etc. if not. Try hooking up a new keyboard and then browse.